# Checking if two strings are anagrams

Tags: c++, strings

Here is my code for checking to see if two strings are anagrams. This seems a little short. Am I missing anything? Both time and space complexity seem to be \$O(1)\$.

```
//Determine if a string is an anagram
//Time complexity: O(1) 
//Space complexity: O

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool anagram(string one, string two) 
{

    if (one.length() != two.length())
    {   
        return false;
    }

    //sorting the strings
    sort(one.begin(), one.end());
    sort(two.begin(), two.end());

    return (one == two);

}

int main() {

    string one;
    string two;

    cout << "please enter in a string: ";
    cin >> one;
    cout << "please enter in another string: ";
    cin >> two;

    cout << anagram(one, two) <<endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Well, if you've got a call to `sort()` in there, then it's not going to be O(1).

Comment: Like @Greg said, it's not O(1). You can implement the algorithm using character occurence counting but it should be at least O(N) with N = maxlength(one, two)

Comment: Oh whoops, totally forgot about calling `sort()`. Thanks!

Comment: if the C++ function `sort()` has an average time complexity of _O(nlogn)_, then would this time complexity be _O(n)_?

Comment: to calculate total complexity of application you just add all Os together, so in your case the input of strings is (2n+2m) (cin+string constructor), then if `n!=m` we have +1, if `n==m` there's +(2n.logn) sort, and string `==` operator is +n again, so total in common case is O(2n+2n+2n.logn+n) = O(5n+2n.logn) = O(n.(5+2.logn)) ... now you "kill" constants, as in big O notation O(5) is same as O(1), so only O(n.logn) remains. You can also imagine it as the biggest complexity eclipses the lesser ones. n*logn is much bigger than n, so O(n+n.logn) is O(n.logn). Just imagine huge `n`, makes sense?

Comment: yes, it makes sense! thanks so much @Ped7g

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Dos and donts

Don't use [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1139697). It's fine for very small programs, but `std::` immediately tells someone that you're using a standard function and not some self-written `sort`.

Use all `#include`'s necessary. `std::sort` is defined in `<algorithm>`. It seems like your C++ distribution includes `<algorithm>` or `stl_algo` in one of the other headers. That's not portable.

Use proper names. `anagram` doesn't tell anything about the function. Does it *create* an anagram? Does it *check* whether something is an anagram of something else? `are_anagrams` or something similar is less ambiguous.

## The issue of \$\mathcal O(1) \$

You cannot get \$\mathcal O(1)\$ for this. You have to view each letter in each word at least once, therefore ending up with \$\mathcal O(n+m)\$ if `one.size()` \$\mathcal O(n)\$ and `two.size()` is \$\mathcal O(m)\$. However, since `one.size() == two.size()` \$n = m\$, otherwise we can find an answer in \$\mathcal O(1) \$.

Regardless, you can solve this in \$\mathcal O(1)\$ additional memory, if you use `std::array<int, 128>` or another fixed/variable size \$O(1)\$ indexable container:

```
typedef std::array<int, 256> character_count_type;

bool is_anagram(const std::string & one, const std::string & two)
{
    if(one.size() != two.size())
    {
        return false;
    }
    character_count_type character_count_one;
    character_count_type character_count_two;

    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < one.size(); ++i){
        assert(0 <= one[i] && one[i] < 256);
        assert(0 <= two[i] && two[i] < 256);
        character_count_one[one[i]]++;
        character_count_two[two[i]]++;
    }
    return character_count_one == character_count_two;
}
```

This has \$\mathcal O(n)\$ worst time complexity, and due to the constant size of `std::array<...>` \$\mathcal O(1)\$ additional space.

Comment: BTW, just for completeness and also to show how high level languages can easily hide O(..) parts: there's hidden O(n) + O(m) outside in the definition of string `one` and `two`. So even when n != m, the whole program runs in O(n+m), although the method itself is O(1) reaping the fruits of "costly" `string` initialization. (if C-like `char *` would be used instead, the same cost would move from initialization of strings to `strlen` call).

Comment: sorry just a little confused - so the overall worst case run time is O(n) not O(nlogn)? and best case would be O(1) (e.g. lengths of strings don't match so return false immediately)?

Comment: @jellyxbean: If you use an algorithm that's based on comparison, it will be O(n log n). If you use an algorithm that's based on counting with a fixed range it will take O(N+n) ([counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)). Since we can consider `N = 128` a constant, it's dropping off in the asymptotic analysis.

Comment: Usually when discussing algorithm on theoretical complexity basis, you take input data as granted and you focus only on algorithm itself. So initialization of `string` is then "for free" and when lengths are different, the `if (n != m)` is O(1). If it would be C-like `char *`, it would be `if (strlen(one) != strlen(two))`, which would be O(n+m)! But in real world performance profiling you will get same result as with `string`, because the cost of `strlen` is hidden in `string(const char *)` constructor. @jellyxbean

Comment: `count[ one[i] ]` should probably be `count[ static_cast<unsigned char>(one[i]) ]`.  You need the string chars to be zero-extended for use as array indices, not sign-extended.